# Can't add ltv to PDF document. Error

Tags: java, pdf, itext, digital-signature, digital-certificate

I'm sign document, using Itext. I have that method:

```
public static void sign(String src, String dest, Certificate[] chain,PrivateKey pk, String digestAlgorithm, String provider,CryptoStandard subfilter, TSAClient tsa )
{

        // Creating the reader and the stamper
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader(src);
        FileOutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(dest);
        PdfStamper stamper = PdfStamper.createSignature(reader, os, '\0');

        // Creating the appearance
        PdfSignatureAppearance appearance = stamper.getSignatureAppearance();
        appearance.setVisibleSignature(new Rectangle(10, 20, 100, 200), 1, "sig");

        // Creating the signature
        ExternalDigest digest = new BouncyCastleDigest();
        ExternalSignature signature = new PrivateKeySignature(pk,
        digestAlgorithm, provider);
        MakeSignature.signDetached(appearance, digest, signature, chain, null,null, tsa, 0, subfilter);


        // ALREADY SIGNED. ADD LTB NOW.
        CrlClient crlClient = new CrlClientOnline("http://crl.mycrl.com/mycrl.crl");
        OcspClient  ocspClient=new OcspClientBouncyCastle();              
    addLtv(DEST, DEST2, ocspClient, crlClient, tsa);

    }
```

and I sign:

```
sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "For Testing", " location", tsa);
```

everything **works**. PDF is **signed well**.

but then, I can't add  ltv. I use code from itext documentation:

```
public static void addLtv(String src, String dest, OcspClient ocsp, CrlClient crl,
        TSAClient tsa) throws IOException, DocumentException,
        GeneralSecurityException {

    PdfReader r = new PdfReader(src);
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(dest);

    PdfStamper stp = PdfStamper.createSignature(r, fos, '\0', null, true);
    LtvVerification v = stp.getLtvVerification();

    AcroFields fields = stp.getAcroFields();

    List<String> names = fields.getSignatureNames();
    String sigName = names.get(names.size() - 1);

    PdfPKCS7 pkcs7 = fields.verifySignature(sigName);

    if (pkcs7.isTsp()) {
            v.addVerification(sigName, ocsp, crl,
                LtvVerification.CertificateOption.SIGNING_CERTIFICATE,
                LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
                LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
    }

    else {
        for (String name : names) {
            v.addVerification(name, ocsp, crl,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateOption.WHOLE_CHAIN,
                    LtvVerification.Level.OCSP_CRL,
                    LtvVerification.CertificateInclusion.NO);
        }
    }
    PdfSignatureAppearance sap = stp.getSignatureAppearance();
    LtvTimestamp.timestamp(sap, tsa, null);
}
```

**EDITED:
everything works, but at line
        LtvTimestamp.timestamp(sap, tsa, null);
I have that error:
    Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not enough space**

that's my pdf:
https://www.dropbox.com/s/o05rw6ubiuslm4j/DOC_SIGNED.pdf

```
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not enough space
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.LtvTimestamp.timestamp(LtvTimestamp.java:103)
at ge.digital.signature.DocumentSigner.DigitalSignature.addLtv(MySignature.java:132)
at ge.digital.signature.DocumentSigner.DigitalSignature.main(MySignature.java:163)
```

Comment: Do you have the stack trace of that exception?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Not enough space
at com.itextpdf.text.pdf.security.LtvTimestamp.timestamp(LtvTimestamp.java:103)
at ge.digital.signature.DocumentSigner.DigitalSignature.addLtv(MySignature.java:132)
at ge.digital.signature.DocumentSigner.DigitalSignature.main(MySignature.java:163)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That `IOException` occurs when the space reserved in the PDF for the integration of the time stamp does not suffice. Thus, you have to change the method `getTokenSizeEstimate` of the `TSAClient` instance `tsa` you call your `sign` method with to return a larger estimate of the time stamp size.

In case of the `TSAClientBouncyCastle` implementation of `TSAClient`, e.g., you can make it return arbitrary estimates instead of the default `4096` if you use the constructor with four arguments:

```
public TSAClientBouncyCastle(String url, String username, String password, int tokSzEstimate)
```

**Some background:** When integrating a signature or a document time stamp into a PDF, you first prepare the PDF with a gap of a given size, then calculate the hash of everything but that gap, then sign or time stamp that hash, and finally integrate the generated signature or time stamp into that gap, e.g.

[image]

(That **/ByteRange** entry is part of the signed content. Thus, one cannot enlarge the gap afterwards.)

Therefore, you have to use some estimate of the size of the generated signature or time stamp before its generation.

In case of document time stamps, this estimate is provided by the `TSAClient` method `getTokenSizeEstimate.`

PS: For still more details cf. [this answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/35131/16096), the Adobe document [Digital Signatures in a PDF](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/DigSig/Acrobat_DigitalSignatures_in_PDF.pdf) (from which I copied the figure above), and the PDF specification ISO 32000-1:2008 made available [here by Adobe](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf).

Comment: thank you. Ok, getTokenSizeEstimate()   Gets the time stamp token size estimate. but , how should I set this estimate size on my pdf?

Comment: You don't set it on the PDF. You change your `TSAClient` implementation to return a better estimate. Unfortunately you haven't shown which `TSAClient` implementation you use, you only use some `tsa` in `sign(SRC, String.format(DEST, 1), chain, pk, DigestAlgorithms.SHA256, provider.getName(), CryptoStandard.CMS, "For Testing", " location", tsa).`

Comment: Now I implements  my TSAClient. I override all the methods.

and I change this:

@Override
 public int getTokenSizeEstimate() {
  return 10000;
 }

it works now.  now it works :-)

Comment: for another methods, I use implementation of TSAClientBouncyCastle. I call that implementation methods :-)

Comment: By default `TSAClientBouncyCastle` returns `4096` as estimate. That does not seem to suffice. I propose you use the `TSAClientBouncyCastle` constructor with four arguments `(String url, String username, String password, int tokSzEstimate)` and try larger estimate values, e.g. `8192.`

Comment: everything works but now Adobe reader tells me that - "Signature is not LTV enabled". do you know why?

Comment: that is my document (added LTV). 
https://www.dropbox.com/s/l4r802rnkmogj72/DOC_SIGNED_LTV.pdf

Comment: Please make that a question in its own right and provide a sample PDF. I'm not that knowledgeable concerning what Adobe accepts there and what not (actually I find Adobe's nomenclature on that subject irritating). Thus, others might know better. **PS** Ah, I see, you provided a sample. But still, please make it a question on its own.

Comment: ok. thank you.
[this is another question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17163770/signature-is-not-ltv-enabled)

Answer (score 1):

If you are not using `TSAClientBouncyCastle` and you created your own `TSAClient` you must set the preferred size of signature, creating a `org.apache.pdfbox.pdmodel.interactive.digitalsignature.SignatureOptions` class, then set something like `signatureOptions.setPreferredSignatureSize(8192*2)`

Comment: The question context is using iText. The context of your answer is using PDFBox.